# Increment count variable if specified rows exist certain values/characters in PHP

Tags: php

I'm a beginner for PHP and are very confused with what I'm doing currently. 
I have a mysql database where all my records are stored in, what I'm trying to do now is to check if specified rows exist certain values/characters, and then increment count variable if it exist.

My database look something like this:

```
id | searchname | searchpassword | question  | ansTrue | ansFalse
---+------------+----------------+-----------+---------+----------
1  | tf-pink    | pink123        | is 1+1=2? | True    | - 
2  | tf-pink    | pink123        | is 1+1=2? | -       | False 
3  | tf-pink    | pink123        | is 1+1=2? | -       | False 
4  | tf-pink    | pink123        | is 1+1=2? | True    | -
```

What I want to do is to count how many true and false are there in the same question, and sent it back to android studio via JSON and display it out.

My php script look like this:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {

        require "conn.php";

        $searchname = $_GET['searchname'];
        $searchpassword = $_GET['searchpassword'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tfparticipator WHERE searchname = '".$searchname."' AND searchpassword = '".$searchpassword."'";
        $r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
        $result = array();

        $countTrue = 0;
        $countFalse = 0;

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) 
        {
            if(($row['ansTrue'] === "True"))
            {
                $countTrue = $countTrue + 1;
            }
            if(($row['ansFalse'] === "False"))
            {
                $countFalse = $countFalse + 1;  
            }               
        }

        array_push($result,array("question"=>$res['question'], "ansTrue"=>$countTrue, "ansFalse"=>$countFalse));

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

The result should be `True = 2` and `False = 2`, but it is now showing me `True = 2` and `False = 1`.

Can I know what have I did wrongly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. Post the code (not as image) you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your suggestion! I'm still figuring out how to post the code instead of posting it as images.

Comment: Hi @Jane, edit the question, paste your code, select it and either digit **`CTRL+K`** or click on the **`{}`** button, and it will be nicely formatted, without the need to use an image.

Comment: Hi @David, it can be done already, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You discard one row of result with the line

```
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
```

If you remove that, you will be nearer your goal

Comment: Thanks, I have tried, but it isn't working for me. It is now showing me empty for the question, ansTrue and ansFalse.

Comment: What are types of columns "ansTrue" and "ansFalse"?

Comment: @RahulNaik varchar

Comment: what is output of:
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
var_dump($res);

Comment: @RahulNaik sorry, i do not understand what you are saying. How do i see the output of this?

Comment: Just add 'var_dump($res); exit;' after $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
Execute it and let me know the output.

Comment: @RahulNaik it shows empty value for question, ansTrue and ansFalse

Comment: My answer told you why your counts are off - you discard one row of your results before your loop. You should be able to figure out why you no longer have that $res['question'] available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: I replace it with the old while loop to this  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))

The result appears to be the same

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) 
        {
print_r($row);
            if(($row['ansTrue'] === "True"))
            {
                $countTrue = $countTrue + 1;
            }
            if(($row['ansFalse'] === "False"))
            {
                $countFalse = $countFalse + 1;  
            }               
        }

let me know result of this. (replace your while loop)

Comment: how do i see the print_r result in android studio?

Comment: Now try this:
if($r)
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
else 
echo "No connection"; 

And let me know if it gives you "No connection" msg.

Comment: It is not showing me "No connection" message, it is showing me the third row of data from the database if i place it outside the while loop. But if i place it in the while loop, it returns a empty value.